# How do I prevent (uninstall) TypeScript installing and referencing it's own @types into AppData\Local

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, types, node-modules

I'm running into a bit of a confusing issue where it seems that `TypeScript` is installing its own copy of `React` into it's own global cache (not sure what its called? assuming thats what it is) and referencing it in my project.

Specifically I end up with two references to React one that is located in the root of my project

```
C:\MyProject\node_modules\@types\react
```

and then another reference in

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\3.0\node_modules\@types\react
```

How do I control and uninstall references that end up in the TypeScript `local` folder? What might I be doing in my project that could be causing this secondary reference?

Here is what my tsconfig.json file looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "/Types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/bin",
    "/obj"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The feature that is downloading the type declarations to `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\3.0\node_modules` is called ["Automatic Type Acquisition"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) and is intended for JavaScript projects.  Since your project has a `tsconfig.json` file, Automatic Type Acquisition should be inactive and any previously downloaded files should not be used; if you have evidence that they are being used and are causing problems with your project, please update the question.  Assuming you are using Visual Studio Code, you can disable Automatic Type Acquisition by setting the `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` setting to `true`.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response and for guiding me in the right direction however no, I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. Are you aware by any chance how to disable it in such a scenario?

Comment: In a quick web search, I wasn't able to find a global switch to disable Automatic Type Acquisition in Visual Studio, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2017#Auto) confirms it should be disabled for projects with `tsconfig.json`.  My question stands: are the downloaded files actually causing a problem with your project?

Comment: Sorry, yes they are, I receive over 190 compiler errors for duplicate declarations, until such time that I delete the offending duplicate folders. I think I might have found the option, testing it now... https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19369

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Yet another way VSCode setup can cause inconsistent behavior between team members.  I wish VSCode would prompt for the install and install the types to devDependencies properly!

Answer (score 7):

These issues comes up depending on your IDE and is resolved in different ways

For Visual Studio 2019:

1. Go to Options-> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript-> Project and Uncheck TypeAcquisition  for Javascript
   [image: OptionsMenuConfig]
2. Close VisualStudio
3. Delete the Folder under C:\Users\ **[Username]**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ **[VersionOfConcern]**
4. Reload Solution and your errors should be gone

VS Code Users should be refer to the tsconfig.json file option:

```
{
[...],
"typeAcquisition": {"enable": false}
}
```

I did not test the Solution for VS Code.